# Ondropdown change label value which is set dynamically goes off

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this scenario where in ondropdown change I'm doing some operations and also setting the value of the label. 
I'm setting the value of the label using labelid.html(). On debugging I'm able to see the value but it goes off once it exits the last brace of the 
UpdateFieldName() method.
How can I ensure I can retain the value. I tried also with innerHtml and innertext but it doesn't work.

```
<label id="lblFieldHeaderNew">Document Template Field</label>
<div class="col-sm-9" style="text-align: left; width: 55%">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FieldTagNameId, new SelectList(Model.TagNames, "DocumentFieldTagId", "CommonName"), FAF.UI.AgentNetGUIFramework.GUIConstants.SELECT,
                    new
                    {
                        id = "ddlDocumentFieldTagId",
                        @onchange = "UpdateFieldName(this)",
                        tabindex = 2,
                        style = "width:250px"
                    })
                <span class="required" style="color: #cf291c" id="spnDdlDocumentFieldTagName">*</span>
            </div>

function UpdateFieldName(obj) {
 $("#lblFieldHeaderNew").html("Document Template Field" +
                    " [" + uniqueTagName + "]");
                }
```

Thank you.

Comment: its a variable holding some value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function UpdateFieldName(value){  
  $('#lblFieldHeaderNew').text("Document Template Field: " + value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select id ="ddl" name="ddl"  onchange="UpdateFieldName(this.value);">
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>

<br/><br/><label id="lblFieldHeaderNew">Document Template Field</label>
```